# How does .NET target framework affect loading of third-party DLLs?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I'm developing an application (C# winforms) that relies upon a vendor-supplied DLL which communicates with hardware.

If I choose a target framework of .NET 4 (or anything higher), I get the following message when attempting to call a method in the referenced DLL:

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'somelibrary.dll': Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)

If I choose a target framework of .NET 2.0 or 3.0, the error does not occur.

I suspect there is an incompatibility or that the library is older than .NET 3.0.

It is likely due to the fact the .DLL launches an executable which acts as a communications handler between the application and a serial port. I have tried setting that application to use various compatibility modes, and to run as administrator, without success.

What can I do to avoid this error and target a more modern .NET platform such as 4.5 or later? (Or am I necessarily stuck due to using a potentially rather old DLL?)

*The application platform target is x86 and I am developing on Win7 x64 with UAC on default settings.*

Comment: Is it a .net assembly you are trying to load? Have you tried to open it with `ildasm.exe`? Is there any additional information provided by `fuslogwv.exe`?

Comment: @ironstone13 I will investigate further with the tools you suggested. I am not sure of the type of assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't say this is 100% correct solution but here is the idea, I believe valid.

This error usually happens when you have missing dependency. In your case dependency for your `somelibrary.dll`. In FW2.0 most files were stored in some `Program files (x86)\Reference Assemblies...`. We know that some things changed in FW4+ and some classes were moved, and assemblies no longer in `Program Files` but downloaded via Nuget. So, what [most likely] happens, when you target FW4.0+, your app start to look for dependencies for v4.0. I would use some disassembler like free `dotPeek`, to look what references you have inside the DLL in question. And then I would try to find these on the machine and see if you don't have version conflicts related to namespaces

Comment: Thanks for the answer/suggestion. I'm not familiar with dotPeek so I will investigate and see if it provides any insight.

Comment: @JYelton Just google JetBrains dotPeek. JetBrains is reputable company that has series of important tools for .net, like `resharper`. Download it, install it and open DLL using that program. Or you can use something like `NDepend`. Surely, there are many tools that will do it. But dotPeek is also a reflector. You can see the code inside. Unless DLL you having is obfuscated. Then dotPeek is of little help.  But I don't know if dependency viewers can see references in obfuscated DLLs